# Django 4.0.10 Migration Error: 'ManyToManyField' object has no attribute 'm2m_reverse_field_name'

Tags: python, django, django-models, attributeerror, django-migrations

I am experiencing a migration issue in Django 4.0.10 using Python 3.12.0 and PostgreSQL as my database. The error occurs during the migration process and seems to be related to ManyToManyField attributes in my CustomUser model.

Error message:
AttributeError: 'ManyToManyField' object has no attribute 'm2m_reverse_field_name'

This issue arises when I run python manage.py migrate. It seems to be triggered by a specific migration file that modifies ManyToManyField relationships.

Here are the relevant parts of my CustomUser model from models.py and the problematic part of the migration file:

models.py (CustomUser model excerpt):
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
# Basic personal information
height = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True, help_text="Height in centimeters")
weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True, help_text="Weight in kilograms")

```
# Health and dietary information
activity_level = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=[('sedentary', 'Sedentary'), ('light', 'Light Activity'), ('moderate', 'Moderate Activity'), ('active', 'Active'), ('very_active', 'Very Active')], default='sedentary', help_text="Activity level of the user")
health_goal = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=[('lose_fat', 'Lose Fat'), ('gain_muscle', 'Gain Muscle'), ('maintain_weight', 'Maintain Weight'), ('improve_fitness', 'Improve Fitness')], default='maintain_weight', help_text="Primary health goal")
dietary_restrictions = models.ManyToManyField('DietaryRestriction', blank=True)
food_preferences = models.ManyToManyField('FoodItem', blank=True)

# Nutritional needs
daily_caloric_intake = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, help_text="Recommended daily caloric intake")
daily_protein_needs = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True, help_text="Recommended daily protein intake in grams")
daily_carb_needs = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True, help_text="Recommended daily carbohydrate intake in grams")
daily_fat_needs = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True, help_text="Recommended daily fat intake in grams")

# User's meal history
meal_history = models.ManyToManyField('Meal', through='MealHistory', related_name='consumed_meals', blank=True)

# User groups for shared meal planning (optional)
user_groups = models.ManyToManyField('UserGroup', related_name='group_members', blank=True)

# Resolving clashing errors between customuser and abstractuser due to using the same related names for many-to-many fields
groups = models.ManyToManyField(
    Group,
    verbose_name=_('groups'),
    blank=True,
    help_text=_('The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions granted to each of their groups.'),
    related_name="customuser_groups",  # Unique related_name
    related_query_name="customuser",  # Unique related_query_name
)

user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(
    Permission,
    verbose_name=_('user permissions'),
    blank=True,
    help_text=_('Specific permissions for this user.'),
    related_name="customuser_permissions",  # Unique related_name
    related_query_name="customuser",  # Unique related_query_name
)
```

Problematic Migration file (0002_dietaryrestriction_fooditem_inventory_usergroup_and_more.py):

## Generated by Django 4.0.10 on 2023-11-16 23:41

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

```
dependencies = [
    ('auth', '0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length'),
    ('core', '0001_initial'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='DietaryRestriction',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('name', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
            ('restriction_type', models.CharField(choices=[('allergy', 'Allergy'), ('diet', 'Diet'), ('other', 'Other')], default='other', max_length=10)),
            ('description', models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)),
        ],
    ),
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='FoodItem',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('name', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
            ('brand_owner', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100, null=True)),
            ('serving_size', models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=5, null=True)),
            ('serving_size_unit', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=10, null=True)),
            ('ingredients', models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)),
            ('dietary_restrictions', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, to='core.dietaryrestriction')),
        ],
    ),
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Inventory',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('quantity', models.IntegerField(help_text='Quantity of the food item in inventory')),
            ('food_item', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='core.fooditem')),
        ],
    ),
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='UserGroup',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('name', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
            ('description', models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)),
            ('group_dietary_restrictions', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, to='core.dietaryrestriction')),
        ],
    ),
    migrations.RemoveField(
        model_name='ingredient',
        name='allergies',
    ),
    migrations.RemoveField(
        model_name='ingredient',
        name='nutrition_info',
    ),
    migrations.RemoveField(
        model_name='customuser',
        name='allergies',
    ),
    migrations.RemoveField(
        model_name='nutritioninfo',
        name='food_item',
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='customuser',
        name='activity_level',
        field=models.CharField(choices=[('sedentary', 'Sedentary'), ('light', 'Light Activity'), ('moderate', 'Moderate Activity'), ('active', 'Active'), ('very_active', 'Very Active')], default='sedentary', help_text='Activity level of the user', max_length=50),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='customuser',
        name='daily_caloric_intake',
        field=models.IntegerField(blank=True, help_text='Recommended daily caloric intake', null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='customuser',
        name='daily_carb_needs',
        field=models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=2, help_text='Recommended daily carbohydrate intake in grams', max_digits=6, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='customuser',
        name='daily_fat_needs',
        field=models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=2, help_text='Recommended daily fat intake in grams', max_digits=6, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='customuser',
        name='daily_protein_needs',
        field=models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=2, help_text='Recommended daily protein intake in grams', max_digits=6, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='customuser',
        name='health_goal',
        field=models.CharField(choices=[('lose_fat', 'Lose Fat'), ('gain_muscle', 'Gain Muscle'), ('maintain_weight', 'Maintain Weight'), ('improve_fitness', 'Improve Fitness')], default='maintain_weight', help_text='Primary health goal', max_length=100),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='customuser',
        name='height',
        field=models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=2, help_text='Height in centimeters', max_digits=5, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='customuser',
        name='meal_history',
        field=models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, related_name='consumed_meals', through='core.MealHistory', to='core.meal'),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='customuser',
        name='weight',
        field=models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=2, help_text='Weight in kilograms', max_digits=5, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='mealhistory',
        name='feedback',
        field=models.TextField(blank=True, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='nutritioninfo',
        name='biotin',
        field=models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='nutritioninfo',
        name='calcium',
        field=models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='nutritioninfo',
        name='chloride',
        field=models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='nutritioninfo',
        name='cholesterol',
        field=models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='nutritioninfo',
        name='chromium',
        field=models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='nutritioninfo',
        name='copper',
        field=models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='nutritioninfo',
        name='folate',
        field=models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='nutritioninfo',
        name='iodine',
        field=models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='nutritioninfo',
        name='iron',
        field=models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='nutritioninfo',
        name='magnesium',
        field=models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='nutritioninfo',
        name='manganese',
        field=models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='nutritioninfo',
        name='molybdenum',
        field=models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='nutritioninfo',
        name='niacin',
        field=models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='nutritioninfo',
        name='pantothenic_acid',
        field=models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='nutritioninfo',
        name='phosphorus',
        field=models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='nutritioninfo',
        name='potassium',
        field=models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='nutritioninfo',
        name='riboflavin',
        field=models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='nutritioninfo',
        name='saturated_fat',
        field=models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='nutritioninfo',
        name='selenium',
        field=models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='nutritioninfo',
        name='sodium',
        field=models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='nutritioninfo',
        name='thiamin',
        field=models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='nutritioninfo',
        name='trans_fat',
        field=models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='nutritioninfo',
        name='vitamin_a',
        field=models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='nutritioninfo',
        name='vitamin_b12',
        field=models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='nutritioninfo',
        name='vitamin_b6',
        field=models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='nutritioninfo',
        name='vitamin_c',
        field=models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='nutritioninfo',
        name='vitamin_d',
        field=models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='nutritioninfo',
        name='vitamin_e',
        field=models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='nutritioninfo',
        name='vitamin_k',
        field=models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='nutritioninfo',
        name='zinc',
        field=models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='customuser',
        name='user_permissions',
        field=models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='Specific permissions for this user.', related_name='customuser_permissions', related_query_name='customuser', to='auth.permission', verbose_name='user permissions'),
    ),
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='meal',
        name='nutrition_info',
        field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='meals', to='core.nutritioninfo'),
    ),
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='mealhistory',
        name='user',
        field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='user_meal_history', to='core.customuser'),
    ),
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='nutritioninfo',
        name='calories',
        field=models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='nutritioninfo',
        name='carbohydrates',
        field=models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='nutritioninfo',
        name='fat',
        field=models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='nutritioninfo',
        name='fiber',
        field=models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='nutritioninfo',
        name='protein',
        field=models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='nutritioninfo',
        name='sugar',
        field=models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.DeleteModel(
        name='Allergy',
    ),
    migrations.DeleteModel(
        name='Ingredient',
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='usergroup',
        name='members',
        field=models.ManyToManyField(to='core.customuser'),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='inventory',
        name='user',
        field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='inventory', to='core.customuser'),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='fooditem',
        name='nutrition_info',
        field=models.OneToOneField(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='food_item', to='core.nutritioninfo'),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='customuser',
        name='dietary_restrictions',
        field=models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, to='core.dietaryrestriction'),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='customuser',
        name='food_preferences',
        field=models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, to='core.fooditem'),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='customuser',
        name='user_groups',
        field=models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, related_name='group_members', to='core.usergroup'),
    ),
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='meal',
        name='ingredients',
        field=models.ManyToManyField(to='core.fooditem'),
    ),
]
```

I originally tried to makemigrations and then migrate without redifining the groups and user_permissions fields, but I ran into the following error:

ERRORS:
auth.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'auth.User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'core.CustomUser.groups'.
HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'auth.User.groups' or 'core.CustomUser.groups'.
auth.User.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'auth.User.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'core.CustomUser.user_permissions'.
HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'auth.User.user_permissions' or 'core.CustomUser.user_permissions'.
core.CustomUser.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'core.CustomUser.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'auth.User.groups'.
HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'core.CustomUser.groups' or 'auth.User.groups'.
core.CustomUser.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'core.CustomUser.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'auth.User.user_permissions'.
HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'core.CustomUser.user_permissions' or 'auth.User.user_permissions'..

Therefore, I tried redefining these fields in my CustomUser model with unique related_name and related_query_name properties, but I am getting the error in the title of this post (Error: 'ManyToManyField' object has no attribute 'm2m_reverse_field_name'). I explored a few other potential fixes without success. Any insights or suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!